# Gerar arquivo .txt com tres colunas

Tags: java

Tenho um sistema onde faço algumas pesquisas no banco e armazeno tudo em um `Array`, porém tenho que montar um layout com esses dados paras que eles possam ser impressos como etiquetas em uma impressora matricial.

A parte das linhas eu já formatei, porém não sei como fazer para que o próximo registro da lista ao invés de ir pra próxima linha vire uma coluna.

Eu preciso deixar dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu consigo obter atualmente é isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso minha consulta retornou apenas dois resultados, o certo seria colocar essa segunda linha em uma coluna como na primeira imagem.

Essa é minha classe que gera o `txt`:

```
public static void gerarTxt(List<Contrato> lista) {

        try {
            FileWriter arq = new FileWriter("C:\\etiqueta.txt");
            PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq);
            for (Contrato item : lista) {
                gravarArq.print(item.getContrato());
                gravarArq.print("\r\n");
                gravarArq.print(item.getContratante());
                gravarArq.print("\r\n");
                gravarArq.print(item.getRua().trim()+", "+item.getNumero());
                gravarArq.print("\r\n");
                gravarArq.print(item.getBairro());
                gravarArq.print("\r\n");
                gravarArq.print(item.getCep() + " "+item.getCidade()+ " "+StringUtils.leftPad(item.getUf(), 22));
                gravarArq.print("\r\n");
                gravarArq.print(".");
                gravarArq.print("\r\n");
            }
            arq.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Como posso transformar essas linhas em colunas?

---

**Update**

Exemplo do projeto no GitHub: https://github.com/sinkz/EtiquetaTeste

Comment: Olha [essa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229140/writing-data-to-text-file-in-table-format) ou [esta aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465086/java-output-to-file-in-table-format) no SOEn.

Comment: Acho que isso resolveria, mas como passar o próximo item da lista na segunda coluna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você conhece a largura da Coluna e ela é fixa (assumo que sim, pois é para uma impressora matricial), você pode usar o método [StringUtils.rightPad](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#rightPad(java.lang.String,%20int)).

De qualquer forma você vai ter que trabalhar com mais de um registro da lista ao mesmo tempo. Por exemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i + 2) {
    Contato c1 = lista.get(i);
    Contato c2 = lista.get(i + 1);

    metodoQueVaiEscreverOText(c1, c2);
```

}

Ainda assim, você precisa controlar o tamanho do array e o index, para evitar o outofboud.

Qualquer coisa cola seu código e exemplos de dados para enriquecermos o exemplo.

Boa sorte

Comment: Sim, a coluna é fixa. Vou tentar dessa maneira e ver se da certo

Comment: Qualquer compartilha o código no editor de sua preferência e damos uma olhada.

Comment: Uma dúvida, sabe como eu poderia padronizar esse layout com StirngUtils?

Comment: Eu quero deixar sempre na mesma posição, tenho que medir o tamanho da String anterior antes de fazer a proxima?

Comment: Eu imagino algo assim:
StringUtils.rightPad(c1.getNome(), 15);
StringUtils.rightPad(c2.getNome(), 15);
//quebra uma linha
StringUtils.rightPad(c1.getContrato(), 15);
StringUtils.rightPad(c2.getContrato(), 15);
//quebra uma linha

Ele vai truncar ou fazer pad para o tamanho informado.
O que vc quer dizer com Layout?

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar dessa forma.

Comment: Por exemplo, posso ter String's com tamanhos diferentes, tenho que fazer que independente do tamanho da String o layout nunca mude, estou utilizando o leftPad e está ficando fora de ordem conforme o tamanho, acho que ele não considera o espaço em branco.

Comment: vou sair pra viajar :/. Segunda continuo tentando, as colunas já estão funcionando só falta alinhar. Obrigado pela ajuda, feliz ano novo.

Comment: De acordo com sua imagem vc deve usar o rightPad e 3 elementos (Contatos) simultaneamente.  
Verifiquei na api, se o tamanho for maior que o esperado, ele nao vai truncar, então usa o substring para quebrar no tamanho.  Conversamos na segunda.

Comment: fiz um projeto de exemplo e coloquei no github se quiser dar uma olhada: https://github.com/sinkz/EtiquetaTeste

Comment: lá tem um arquivo `.txt`  o primeiro layout é gerado pelo sistema, e a parte de baixo é como estou tentando deixar. De começo estou tentando fazer com duas colunas.

Comment: Acho que consegui resolver, mas agora estou tendo problemas com o índice :p kk

Comment: Problema resolvido, utilizei o rightPad mesmo ao invés do left

Comment: Legal. Desculpa a demora, só consegui acesso à internet agora. Valeu

Comment: Tranquilo, dei uma fuçada e consegui. kkk